# Notify called before wait

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading about multi-threading, when I read about `wait()` and `notify` methods. I am having a doubt that what happens if `notify()` method completes before `wait()` method.

`Wait()` method will wait again? or previous notification is valid to move further?

Comment: I hope you know you could just try it.

Comment: i tried it , previous notification works fine...but still confirming.. i am right?

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for [`Object#wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) says

> Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the
>   `java.lang.Object.notify()` method or the `java.lang.Object.notifyAll()`
>   method for this object.

So, when you call

```
someObject.wait();
```

it will wait for the **following** invocation of

```
someObject.notify(); // or notifyAll()
```

Comment: so you mean previous notification is valid

Comment: @user2985842 I'm saying a `notify()` happening before a `wait()` has absolutely no effect on it.

Answer (score 0):

if notify() method is invoked before the execution of wait() method, then the waiting thread will remain into waiting state forever.
In Such scenarios, If there is no guarantee of getting back the notification then always wait for a certain period of not i.e use wait(milliSecond)/wait(milliSecond,NanoSecond) instead of wait() which will wait for infinite time and only proceed further when got notified.

refer the example below for better understanding -

```
class MainThread extends Thread {
public void run() {
    ChildThread ct = new ChildThread();
    ct.start();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    synchronized (ct) {
        System.out.println("Main Thread started");
        try {

            ct.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Main THread controlled returned");
        System.out.println(ct.total);
    }
}}

class ChildThread extends Thread {
int total = 0;

public void run() {
    synchronized (this) {
        System.out.println("Child Thread started");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            total++;
        }
        System.out.println("Child Thread passed notify");
        this.notify();
    }
}}

public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    MainThread mt = new MainThread();

    mt.start();
}}
```